# Running Stepper motors (at least 2) at the same time

Tags: arduino-mega

Is there a way to run a Stepper motor with Arduino MEGA 2560 with A4988 driver component.

I am using this https://github.com/laurb9/StepperDriver library and with this code,

```
Serial.println("Starting motor ALL");
int steps = atoi(third.c_str());
int duration = atoi(fourth.c_str());

BasicStepperDriver stepper1(steps, DIR, STEP, ENBL);
stepper1.enable();
stepper1.setMicrostep(MICROSTEPS);
stepper1.setRPM(MAX_RPM);

BasicStepperDriver stepper2(steps, DIR_2, STEP_2, ENBL_2);
stepper2.enable();
stepper2.setMicrostep(MICROSTEPS);
stepper2.setRPM(MAX_RPM);

int starttime = millis();
int endtime = starttime;
while ((endtime - starttime) <= duration) // mS
{
     stepper1.rotate(90);  
     stepper2.rotate(90);  
     endtime = millis();
}
stepper1.disable();
stepper2.disable();
Serial.println("DONE");
```

The problem with this is that each stepper motor in this code waits for each other and not simultaneously like a DC motor. What could be done to make it work simultaneously?

Comment: Use a different library. This one is blocking code-execution while rotating.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [AccelStepper](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper) library. It can control both steppers at the same time. Also provides some useful [examples](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/AFMotor_MultiStepper_8pde-example.html)

AccelStepper with more than one stepper also requires the [Adafruit Motor library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Motor-Shield-library) to be installed.